# Hide all fields except Title in a SharePoint alert email

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

What I need is exactly that: to be able to hide **ALL** the fields in a SharePoint alert mail except for say Title.

Now before you mark this as a duplicate of
**[Hide field in SharePoint alert email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120427/hide-field-in-sharepoint-alert-email)**,
please note that the above link does solve this, but this would require specifying each and every field to be hidden.

> The properties element allows you to include or exclude fields from
>   the list that would be shown in the email notification. The example
>   below demonstrates how to exclude fields for both the immediate and
>   summary (digest) alerts.

```
<Properties>
  <ImmediateNotificationExcludedFields>ID;Author;Editor;Modified_x0020_By;Created_x0020_By;_UIVersionString;ContentType;TaskGroup;IsCurrent;Attachments;NumComments;</ImmediateNotificationExcludedFields>
  <DigestNotificationExcludedFields>ID;Author;Editor;Modified_x0020_By;Created_x0020_By;_UIVersionString;ContentType;TaskGroup;IsCurrent;Attachments;NumComments;</DigestNotificationExcludedFields>
</Properties>
```

The implications of this would mean that if there is a new field added, I would then have to update this custom template.

I was wondering if it was possible to by default just hide every field, and just specify what I want shown instead (in this case, just the Title).

Is this possible? Or am I stuck with having to state one by one what I want hidden?

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a specific list, I would just create a workflow in SharePoint designer that sends an email whenever something changes on the list.  This gives you 100% control over the look and feel of the notification that is sent out.  However, it would not allow individuals to set up their own alerts.

Comment: Yeah, this has been brought up as well, but the thing about the subscription model to this makes this unfeasible.

Comment: Sorry, from what I've read, it's (almost) impossible to do this. From what I've read, everyone that has tried has given up and went with custom event handlers or workflows.  Here's hoping you find something else.